# define a redirect from dynamic URL in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to redirect the users, to their user profile page, after they successfully login *(or their login is successfully authenticated)*. I take the users to their profile pages through the dynamic hyper link below:

```
  #/{{getAccountTypeName($parent.user.account_type)}}/{{$parent.user.handle}}
```

And I've located where my users are authenticated at login. But How can I take a dynamically populated URL such as above, in angular JS and call it as a redirect in the below authentication statement. `(I am new to angular)`

```
            var email = $scope.loginForm.email;
            var password = $scope.loginForm.password;
            auth.login(
                email,
                password,
                function (data) {
                    if (data.success == true) {
                        $scope.initLogin();
                        $scope.loginCallback(data);
                        $scope.showWelcome = true;
                        addPointsLogin();
                        $("#welcomeModal").modal();
                        $scope.cancel = function () {
                            $("#welcomeModal").modal("hide");
                        };

                    }
                    else {
                        alert(data.error_message);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.controller('myCntrl', ['$http', '$scope', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location',
      function($http, $scope, $route, $routeParams, $location){
  var email = $scope.loginForm.email;
  var password = $scope.loginForm.password;
            auth.login(
                email,
                password,
                function (data) {
                    if (data.success == true) {
                        $scope.initLogin();
                        $scope.loginCallback(data);
                        $scope.showWelcome = true;
                        addPointsLogin();

                        $location.path(path); // Put your path here
                        console.log($routeParams); // Here you get your URL data

                        $("#welcomeModal").modal();
                        $scope.cancel = function () {
                            $("#welcomeModal").modal("hide");
                        };

                    }
                    else {
                        alert(data.error_message);
                    }
                }
}]);
```

Comment: Yes, but how could I include my dynamic URL in this solution?

Comment: #/{{getAccountTypeName($parent.user.account_type)}}/{{$parent.user.handle}}

Comment: var username = getAccountTypeName($parent.user.account_type); var parent =$parent.user.handle; $location.path('#/'+username+'/'+parent);

Comment: Could you show me how that would work within the solution above? Once I include the variables, how could I call them above?